# Android How to screen touch event in service?

Tags: android

I wonder 'How to screen touch event in service(Or anywhere)?'

I find way use 'adb' but Mobizen application not use 'adb'

If you know this, just talk to me hint. Please.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for dispatch touch event from background service?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at Touch events - http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Services do not have UI, as they run in the background, so you cannot detects touch events on a service.

Comment: but how to generate touch event in background..? :(

Comment: Do you mean, you want to listen for touch events on other apps?